# Improved model of a fishery: $\dot N=rN(1-\frac{N}{K})-H\frac{N}{A+N}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, biology, nonlinear-dynamics

Strogatz exercise $3.7.4.a:$

An improved model of a fishery is:

$$\dot N=rN\left(1-\frac{N}{K}\right)-H\frac{N}{A+N}.$$

a) Give a biological interpretation of the parameter $A$; what does it measure?

Here's what I did:

I non-dimensionalized the system $(\frac{dN}{dt}=N(1-N)-h\frac{N}{a+N})$ and used the 'Manipulate' function of Mathematica to gain a better understanding of what '$a$' is biologically, but still, I couldn't see it.

So here's my question: How could I approach answering such a question and gain a better insight of it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: What are the parameters?  Presumably $N$ is the number of fish.  What are $r,H,K?  What is the model you are improving?  The same without $A$?  The interpretation of $A$ will depend on understanding the model.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes, I even tried 'Mathematical Biology' by Murray. And also this article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0198971582900011.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, $N$ is the number of fish, $r$ is how fast the population grows, $K$ is the carrying capacity, and $H$ is the harvesting rate. In the original model, $H$ is constant which creates a simple saddle-node bifurcation and it is very easy to comprehend.

Comment: @Heptapod: See number $3$: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m207/set3_sol.pdf

Comment: The others and references provide some good descriptions of A. As for the biological name, A is often called "the half-saturation constant".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term $HN/(A+N)$ is a typical **saturation** term (see [Michaelis–Menten kinetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics), or [type II functional response](http://www.tiem.utk.edu/~gross/bioed/bealsmodules/holling.html)).

For small $N$ (in comparison to $A$), the harvesting is roughly proportional to how much fish there is, since $HN/(A+N) \approx (H/A)N$.

But for large $N$ (in comparison to $A$) there is saturation; no matter how much fish there is available, one can't harvest at a higher rate than $H$, since $HN/(A+N) \nearrow H$ as $N \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are expected to do any manipulation, you are just supposed to explain what $A$ does in the model.  I would answer along the lines of

It reflects that harvesting gets less when fish get scarce.  If $N=A$ the harvesting drops in half compared to when $N$ is very large compared with $A$.